# In prestashop 1.6 not able to upload product images

Tags: php, .htaccess, prestashop, dropbox, prestashop-1.6

We have an online shopping portal gergstore.com

The vendors are sending product images in bulk through the dropbox, but unfortunately we are unable to get the product images from the dropbox, we will get a blank image.

I have tried to solve this issue in many ways but not getting the solution.

Comment: What dropbox are we talking about here?

Comment: ok I solved the issue actually the image link was https://www.dropbox.com/s/hiihfk9jihe8t9v/A%20Mark%20Of%20The%20Danger%20Warning%20Asus%20Zenfone%202%20Phone%20Case.jpg?dl=0           Then I changed to                                                                                                                                                             that is changed                                                                                                        dl=0 to dl=1 for all the images in the csv files and uploaded now I am getting the images

Comment: Glad you could solve this. You should post your comment as the answer and accept it.

Comment: In the image link s/hiihfk9jihe8t9v/A%20Mark%20Of%20The%20Danger%20Warning%20Asus%20Zenfone%202%20Phone%20Case.jpg?dl=0  the last 4 characters dl=0 I changed it to dl=1 means dl=0 reads the image from the dropbox dl=1 downloads the image from the dropbox

Comment: @Julien Lachal  :ok Julien Lachal I did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the image link
`s/hiihfk9jihe8t9v/A%20Mark%20Of%20The%20Danger%20Warning%20Asus%20Zenfone%202%20‌​Phone%20Case.jpg?dl=0`
I changed the last 4 characters `dl=0` to `dl=1`.
`dl=0` reads the image from Dropbox `dl=1` downloads the image from Dropbox